# How to sign in to Windows 10 with local account?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have created a local user account in Windows 10 and set a password, but when I try to switch user from my Microsoft-account to the local one, the login screen prompts me for an email-address and a password. Typing the username I created into the email-textbox doesn't let me sign in.

How can I sign in to a local account without an email-address?

The option "Sign in with a local account instead" is missing from Settings > Account > Your info

Screenshot from Settings > Account:

[image]

Comment: "How can I sign in to a local account without an email-address?" - Disconnect the local account from the Microsoft Account.  Is your current problem that, you are unable to log into the account, that has now been linked to a Microsoft Account?

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that when I am signed into my Microsoft-account, I want to switch accounts to the local account. I can't switch user, because there is no username-prompt on the login screen, only an email-prompt.

Comment: You cannot log into a local account that has been linked to a Microsoft Account.  While account exists to a certain point, it's inaccessible, while linked to the Microsoft Account.  The account should be listed with the other accounts that exists on the system.

Comment: @Ramhound So, if I'm signed into my Microsoft account, how would I go about switching to a local account? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Settings -> Accounts`

Comment: That account shown in the picture doesn't look like a local account. Local accounts have the phrase "Local Account" written on the line ABOVE the term "Administrator"

Comment: @Tonny That's the thing, it's not a local account. I'm on my Microsoft-account, wanting to switch to a local account. I have created a local account but i can't figure out how to switch to it.

Comment: @CKTS That is very weird. On every Windows 10 machine I have ever seen there is a line on that same screen that says "Sign in with a local account instead" (when looked from a Microsoft account and that says "Sign in with a Microsoft account" when looked at it with a local account. The only way to disable this AFAIK is a domain policy, but that would mean the computer isn't yours, but belongs to your employer (or school) and you shouldn't mess with this yourself. (There would also be a red line at the top of that screen saying: "Some of these settings are managed by your organization")

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new local account. Your current one can't work
because it's linked to a Microsoft account.

From
[Create a local user or administrator account in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-20de74e0-ac7f-3502-a866-32915af2a34d#WindowsVersion=Windows_10):

- Run *Start > Settings > Accounts > Family & other users*
- Select "Add someone else to this PC"
- Select "I don't have this person's sign-in information"
- On the next page, select "Add a user without a Microsoft account"
- Enter a user name, password, or password hint, or choose security
  questions, and then select Next.

See the above article if you want to change this local user account
to an administrator account.

Comment: I did all this, but after the account is created, how do I switch to it?

Comment: To switch to the new account, enter *Settings > Accounts > Your info* and click “Sign in with a local account instead”.

Comment: That option is missing, see my added screenshot.

Comment: Do you see your new account in *Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users*? If not, then right-click in the empty space and select "New User..." and do it from there.

Comment: @CKTS - You can enabled the group policy the lists users on the machine provided you are an Administrator on the machine and are absolutely NOT connected to an active directory domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer, when at the login screen, select other users and then for the email address, type "./" and then your local account username.

Comment: Please explain why this happens.  At the moment this sounds like a comment, not an answer.